# Browser asks for password several times .htaccess using subdomain

Tags: server, apache2, password

I have a private homepage and I want to password-protect it using .htaccess. This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
AuthName MySite
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /what/ever/.htpasswd
require valid-user

#making embeded videos work in wordpress
<Files ~ "\.(mp4|m4v)">
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
order allow,deny
allow from all
satisfy any
</Files>

# Code for Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /whatever/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /whatever/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#End Wordpress

Options -Indexes
```

It's located in the folder directory directed for the homepage.

Problem is that when accessing the server via it's subdomain the browser keeps asking for login/pass. If pressing cancel after two atempts one is directed to the page anyway.

If trying to access the webpage without subdomain, like this: www.mypage.com/privatesite, the browser asks for password once and then it's done. No problems.

This is the homepages .conf file in apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName my.site.com
ServerAlias www.my.site.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@site.se
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Directory "/var/www/html/site">
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried not using .htaccess and just using .htpasswd instead? That's what I'm doing [here](https://www.brownvpn.tk/mpd).

Comment: @TheBrownOne Thanks! That actually worked out, partly. I used this page to set it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548992/htpasswd-without-htaccess. Now it only asks for password once when I use the subdomain, but I can bypass it easily by going through www.site.com/folder. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Use a Location Directive in your conf.

Answer (score 0):

Apache got confused with too many requests for passwords from different places.

By only using this code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/folder/">
    AuthUserFile  /home/user/.htpasswd
    AuthName  "Pass"
    AuthType Basic
    require user username
</Directory>
```

In 000-default.conf solved the problem.

I thought every .conf file needed it's own directions for password. They don't.